# Create a CardDav client to fetch contacts from server in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, contacts, carddav

I have read up almost all the questions here on SO regarding carddav and didn't find an answer for my question. Do let me know if this already answered.

I need to create an app which implements a CardDav client to fetch contacts from the server. I am aware of using existing AddressBook framework and make iOS do the heavy lifting. However, our app is more catered to elderly people and business feels not all might be able to navigate into settings and add server information manually. (I am looking into automating this, information from another SO thread).

1. Is there a SDK available in objective C that I can use to fetch/edit and delete contacts.
2. Is there a way to avoid syncing of existing contacts from other sources like iCloud or Gmail to be synced back to our server when default account is switched.

Any pointers or guide to build a native carddav client is deeply appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: This question seems too broad to me. iOS itself doesn't include an SDK for CardDAV access. If you want to write an own client you might be able to grab some code from [SOPE](http://sope.opengroupware.org/en/sope_ical/), but that doesn't contain a shrink-wrapped/standalone CardDAV client. If you just want to automate the setup, iOS configuration profiles might be something for you.

Comment: Also, I don't understand the second question.